# PhpStorm 7 lose focus input focus when searching for a file on GNOME shell 3.10 and sloppy mouse focus mode

Tags: focus, phpstorm, gnome-shell

I have a really annoying bug: when I hit CTRL+SHIFT+N to search for a file, sometimes it loses the focus, and characters entered that are put into the file currently being edited, but then it regains it, and continues the correct behaviour (this happens without moving the mouse!!!).

When I used unity on ubuntu 14.04 (with sloppy focus mode), it was ok, but with Gnome shell 3.10, having sloppy mode when changing window focus, it creates this bug. Does anyone know a solution for this?

It breaks my developement because I don't even observ I have a new character in the file, and it drives me crazy.
Thx.

Comment: fwiw it happens for me too using Ubuntu 12.04.5. I'm using metacity as WM on an xfce desktop, with focus set to click.

Answer (score 4):

See comments in [IDEA-112015](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112015) for possible workarounds. The issue is indeed related to 'cursor following mouse' (i.e. sloppy focus) mode

Comment: Well, now I changed the focus mode to mouse from sloppy (mainly the same thing), and it seems to work now, but not sure if this is what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling in registry: 
`actionSubsystem.xWindow.remove.focus.from.nonFocusable.popup‌​s` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and select "Registry")

It works in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: this works for me on Antergos Linux / PHPstorm  2017.2  ;-)

Comment: Registry key now is `actionSystem.xWindow.remove.focus.from.nonFocusable.popups`... Giving this a try... Has been driving me nuts... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## 2019 answer

You want to prevent other processes (such as the desktop environment) from *stealing focus*.

1. Open PhpStorm (or IntelliJ, or whatever other JetBrains IDE you use)
2. Go to Help -> Edit Custom Properties
3. Add the line `suppress.focus.stealing=false`
4. Restart the IDE

Other processes will no longer steal focus when you try to move focus to the IDE.